# with php, how can I send data via POST simulating in full a form submit?

Tags: php, curl

My problem is this: I have an online service which hosts my customer's catalogue.
This service requires authentication, but I have one single username/pwd.
My customer, instead, wants to manage separately every single user with their own user/pwd and access statistics. So what I did was to build my own account management, so far so good.
What I need to do now is to add a login form which users should fill in with their own credentials; once sent, the script should proceed with the authentication and, if everything's ok, increment the access count, send the remote system's login data via POST and redirect the browser to the response page, exaclty the same way as a normal form would do.
I tried using `curl` this way:

```
if (authenticate($_POST['usr'],$_POST['pwd'])) {
    $url = "http://www.foo.com/login.php";
    $postdata = http_build_query(array('username'=>"foo",'password'=>"bar"));
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

but I end up loading the destination page's data into my own page, instead of being redirected to the site.
What should I do?
P.S. I would avoid resorting to an hidden form submitted via JS, if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: So how did you solve this eventually ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
```

From the manual:

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of
>   curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: everything works as it should, except that what I need is the browser to be _redirected to the target page_, exaclty as it would after a form submit, instead it _loads the target page into mine_

Comment: @Lucius cURL is server side. It won't redirect the browser. You might need to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Using a JS is way too unsafe, since it would imply exposing user name and password, which should not be disclosed for obvious reasons..  
Isn't there any other way other than cUrl, then?

Comment: @Lucius have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue where I need to use cURL to submit form data with a hidden username and password that cannot be exposed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you see the whole picture of what you are trying to do. Basically, redirect won't help you, because authentication is not URL-based, it's cookie or session based. In other words, you can't authenticate youself (which happens when you emulate form submit on that website with hidden credentials) and make your visitor get that authentication for himself. Redirect won't help you here. Even if you redirect him, he's not authenticated. Your server is, because it submited the form, not the user himself.

What I don't get is you are ok with authenticating a user with that hidden credentials and then giving him full access to the statistics, why not just give him the access? You are providing him with full access to everything, but don't give him the login and password?

As a side not, POST redirect is not possible, so you can't redirect him on form submit with forged POST data. All POST data is lost on redirect.

As an ugly workaround, I'll suggest the following: you can authenticate yourself like you are doing now, and then let user browse the statistics from your website, similar to what proxies do. You can then change all links on the page to something like `yoursite.com/viewstats/?page=URL`, where `URL` is the page of the statistics site user wants to see. You grab that page and show it to user. You will need to change relative paths to css/js files to keep their design, and you will also need to change all within-website links like this `"/viewstats/?page=" . urlencode($old_url)` so they point on your proxy-like gate.

Comment: Ok, the picture is clearer now, thank you!
As for your doubts, the service is an online catalogue that requires authentication, but doesn't provide a user management system.
Authenticated users have access only to the remote catalogue. Usage statistics and user management are reserved to the site's owner, are hosted on our own server, and require their own separate authentication.